# ajax get wrong value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I used ajax for my current project with laravel and  i try  to pass value of textbox using ajax but it pass `R` every time, even if i pass the wrong variable with ajax. my code is as below

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Total Amount</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_amount" value="123" name="total">
 </div>
```

javascript code

```
    $("#id_label_multiple").on('change', function () {
        var list = $("#id_label_multiple").val();
        var total = $("#total_amount").val();
        console.log()
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ action('hkcontroller@getTotal') }}",
            data: {
                lists: list, total: total, "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#msg').html('Received ' + data + ' stones form exporter successfully!')
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

laravel method

```
public function getTotal(Request $request)
{
    $list = @$request['lists'];
    $total = @request['total'];
    return $total;
}
```

varibale `list` work fine but `total` always return value `R`, when it print first time `log` that time it print correct value in console, but second time in `success` function of ajax it print always `R`. where i made mistake??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
$total = @request['total'];
```

to this:

```
$total = @$request['total'];
          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:

```
$("#id_label_multiple").on('change', function () {
        var list = $("#id_label_multiple").val();
        var total = $("#total_amount").val();
        console.log()
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ action('hkcontroller@getTotal') }}",
            data: "lists="+list+"&total="+total+"&_token={{ csrf_token()}}",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#msg').html('Received ' + data + ' stones form exporter successfully!')
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```